# Overriding list styles

Tags: html, css, list, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a stylesheet being used for multiple CSS pages in an ASP.Net site. Two of these pages have lists that are styled almost exactly the same.

E.g

Style for all pages:

```
li { padding-left:40px; text-indent:-44px; }
```

Style for list that needs a seperate style :

```
.customlistitem {padding-left:90px; text-indent:0px; }
```

And then in the actual page the list that requires slightly different style :

```
<li class="customlistitem">
```

Problem is the customlistitem selector isn't overriding the style in the stylesheet. Why is this ?

Comment: you can use !important

Comment: No, the use of `!important` is discouraged! Check [James answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23929334/2600397), that's the way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to increase the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) on your selector:

```css
li.customlistitem {
    ...
}
```

`.customlistitem` by itself does have a higher specificity than just `li`, so I imagine your selectors are a bit more complex than what you've included in your question. Regardless, higher specificity is the way to go.